# Installed Ubuntu (dual boot) and now Windows 8 doesn't boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

It shows this whenever I try to boot Windows from `grub`

```
error: can't find command 'drivemap'.
error: invalid EFI file path.

Press any key to continue...
```

I've tried the automatic boot repair and that didn't work. Anyone know how to fix this?
I did make a seperate partition in my D drive for Ubuntu so Windows should still work.

Boot repair info here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6840502/

Comment: Please post answers as answers and avoid posting solutions in the question body. I suggest to take a quick tour on how this site works. http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: If any of the solutions given here don't work, you could try this http://askubuntu.com/a/676106/452738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do here is to run "boot repair" and you should see a new boot option
for Windows to boot in "UEFI mode".

Alternatively, if this fails, try either the "re-partiton command" on your drive, or uninstall Ubuntu and re-install it.

Answer (score 0):

You show both Windows & Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode. But you also have a BIOS Windows type boot loader in the MBR. If you try to boot in BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode it will not work.

You also ran the Boot-Repair "buggy" UEFI. Best no to run that unless you have confirmed that you only can boot Windows from UEFI menu and no ubuntu entry will work. That renames the Windows boot file to really be shim or grub and boot to grub menu. Then you only can boot Windows from grub menu as the bkpbootmgfw.efi. 
If you can boot ubuntu entry, in Boot-Repair:

To undo & to rename files to their original names, you just need to tick the "Restore EFI backups" option of Boot-Repair.

You have the older version of grub that has the os-prober bug. Entries created by os-prober are the old BIOS type and will never work. They look like this:

```
Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda4)
```

grub2's os-prober creates wrong style (BIOS) chain boot entry Fixed with 13.10

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1024383