# Problems logging into windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8, and it works fine, but when i restart the computer, in the dual boot i get to choose:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)
- System setup

If i click **Ubuntu** it goes right to Ubuntu and everything is fine.

But clicking on **Windows** i get the error:

```
/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(a0341d0,0)/PCI(2,1f)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(1,800,fa000,41ea8f607930ff48,2,2)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot)/File(bootmgfw.efi)/EndEntire
error: cannot load image.

Press any key to continue...
```

I press Enter and i get:

```
                        GNU GRUB version 2.02^beta2-9
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub> _
```

Here i type `exit` and hit enter, then i see the **Boot Manager**:

```
UEFI BOOT:
ubuntu...
Windows Boot Manager ...
...
```

I choose **Windows...** and finally enter Windows.
Why do i have to go through all this process to enter Windows?

*note: i tried Windows 8's 'boot repair' but it didn't solve the problem*

**edit:**

The solutions in the answers sound too risky for me... Is there a way i could at least make windows the default o.s? In the current situation if i restart the computer and leave it without touching anything it loads automatically to Ubuntu. Can i make it load to Windows 8 as a default?

Comment: It looks like you might have hit [bug #1091464 - Unable to chainload Windows 8 with Secure Boot enabled](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464). You can apparently workaround this by disabling Secure Boot. Another workaround is discussed in the answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/335019/unable-to-boot-windows-8-after-ubuntu-installation) which suggests to use rEFInd boot loader.

Answer (score 1):

I find it odd that it gives you the windows boot manager, instead of windows itself. Try updating grub from ubuntu. A tutorial can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

The boot-repair tool can also give a "Bootinfo" summary to help us dig deeper into the issue if the repair tool does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use this software - EasyBCD.

For just one more time, try to boot into Windows using the above method. Then install EasyBCD.

Once installed launch BCD, there you can see your boot entries. You may then edit your boot entries or add new entries or do something else. :p

This might solve your problem. :)