# cannot boot windows 8.1 after installing ubuntu 14.04 (for dual boot)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

yesterday I installed ubuntu 14.04 in my windows 8.1(preinstalled) lenovo 14R willing to dual boot it with windows 8.1.I created a different partition and a 2gb partition for swap. Though i did NOT DISABLE FAST BOOT of windows 8. I am a new linux user and I have no idea of fixing it. Now I can only boot Ubuntu and when I choose windows boot manager (instead of ubuntu in the begining) i see this screen:

/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(a0341d0,0)/PCI(0,13)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,1f4800,82000, 03b335deed640d49,2,2)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot)/File(bootmgfw.efi)/EndEntire
error: cannot load image
Press any key to continue. . .

i followed the instructions of this video.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOz66FC0pWU

The only thing that was different was that at 8:40 there wasn't anything like dev/sda1/windows 8(loader) in the menu that is in the video.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Lets see what is the status of your installs. Post the link that running the summary report gives: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Suggest not running any auto fixes until someone has reviewed your install.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but finally things changed a bit. So I would like to add that if i go to boot options and put the windows boot loader first windows is booting normally and working properly. The only issue is that i cannot select windows via the ubuntu menu that appears when starting the pc which should normally allow me to quickly select between ubuntu and windows without changing the boot order every time. 
Thank you.

Comment: That could be that Windows is in UEFI boot mode and Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. Or you may have secure boot on as grub menu currently will not boot Windows from grub menu when secure boot is on (bug). If Ubuntu is in BIOS boot mode you should be able to convert to UEFI boot mode with Boot-Repair. But again best to see details.

Comment: Try this solution http://askubuntu.com/a/676106/452738

Answer (score 0):

I watched the video and i would recommend to anyone unfamiliar with hard drive partitions and master boot records not to attempt this.

From what i saw the guy presenting this video was installing a virtual box (An operating system inside an operating system). That may have given him a different context for the installation. What i suspect is that because you could not specify NOT to overwrite the windows "boot record", well it did scrapping your windows 8 install.

You may want to google file recovery software and use windows 7 with the ubuntu option to install alongside windows instead of doing the part of partitioning windows/linux yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but finally things changed a bit. So I would like to add that if i go to boot options and put the windows boot loader first windows is booting normally and working properly. The only issue is that i cannot select windows via the ubuntu menu that appears when starting the pc which should normally allow me to quickly select between ubuntu and windows without changing the boot order every time. 
Thank you.

Comment: I would like to add that attempting this myself it is possible that on a pre installed Windows machine, the partition table is not of MBR type. Booting the "try me" portion of Ubuntu lets you use a tool to fix that issue. I would have to research the name but that much would give people something to look into if they run into this particular problem. Sorry i didn't remember the tool's name.