# booting problem with windows8.1 and ubuntu12.04

Tags: dual-boot

I installed windows8.1 on my new laptop after that i installed ubuntu12.04 as dual OS .
now i am able to use only ubuntu, windows is not booting.
how can i get my windows back to use as dual OS.
Both the OS installations are in legacy mode

Comment: Do you see the grub menu?

Comment: dos and ubuntu are there

Comment: i have posted an answer, follow those steps and see if it works

Comment: Try this solution, http://askubuntu.com/a/676106/452738

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps from Ubuntu :

1. Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> Or Search `Terminal` in  Dash.
2. Enter the following command in Terminal :

   `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

   (This will open grub configuration file in `gedit`.)
3. Edit the file and change following options as following (remove comments # before any of below lines) and save the file :

   `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`
   `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`
   `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false`
   `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`
4. Run the following command in new instance of terminal :

   `sudo update-grub`
5. Restart your computer, you should be now able to boot Windows if you
   did partition your system correct