# unable to boot into windows 8 inspite of dual booting

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-8

I have a **lenovo g505** with windows 8. I just downloaded and installed the latest version of **Ubuntu(18.04 LTS)** by following all the procedures of dual boot.
 Now when I want to go to windows, after restarting my PC it shows following options

```
1.ubuntu
2.advanced options for ubuntu
3.windows boot manager
4.system setup.
```

when I click on the *windows boot manager* I get an everlasting purple screen. I checked in the files and found all of my windows files are present in windows 8 disc, yet I am unable to go into windows 8, so please suggest a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot Windows 8 after Ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335019/unable-to-boot-windows-8-after-ubuntu-installation)

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Boot Repair

1. Boot with a Live USB
2. Install `boot-repair` [instructions here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
3. Run `boot-repair` and click recommended repair option
4. Accept option to generate the `boot-repair` report to the Internet
5. Post the Internet link into your question if it still doesn't boot up.